# Sitecore 7.0 - Sitecore.Apps.Loader.dll - What is it?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Sitecore.Apps.Loader.dll

I loaded this one to find out what was inside and I couldn't find any documentation on the internet about it.  It only has one namespace which is AppService.

Anybody know what this dll does for Sitecore?
Can anyone provide how this is useful for me?

Comment: It's most likely used by the [Sitecore App Center](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sac/getting_started_with_sitecore_app_center_20-a4.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore.Apps.Loader.dll is used by Sitecore App Store/Center within the sitecore client.

Comment: Anything I can do with it C# wise?  Or is it just for the App Center?

Comment: As far as I know it's only used by the App Center and no real use within your custom implementation.